# TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable any explenation?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, prediction, machine-translation

input is an english sentence and when i run i get the error

**Code:**

```
  saved_weights = find_checkpoint_file('.')                                              
  print('please enter the value')                                                        
  user_input1 = input()                                                                  
  if len(saved_weights) == 0:                                                            
      print("The network hasn't been trained! Program will exit...")                     
      sys.exit()                                                                         
  else:                                                                                  
      X_test = load_test_data(user_input1, X_word_to_ix, MAX_LEN)                        
      X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=4, dtype='int32')                            
      model.load_weights(saved_weights)                                                  
      predictions = np.argmax(model.predict[X_test])                                     
      sequences = ()                                                                     
      for prediction in predictions:                                                     
          sequence = ' '.join([y_ix_to_word[index] for index in prediction if index > 0])
          print(sequence)                                                                
          sequences.append(sequence)                                                     
      np.savetxt('test_result', sequences, fmt='%s')
```

this line though outs error:

```
      predictions = np.argmax(model.predict[X_test])
```

**error:**

> TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have such code, it is not correct, use this:

```
predictions = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test))
```

Comment: thanks for replying but still got the same problem                                                                                       and now i got this error                                                                                                AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'argmax'

Comment: @BlackSnow What do you mean the same problem? On which line do you get such error? is np a list somehow?

Comment: sorry i made a mistake

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60585905/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-argmax-and-numpy-axiserror-axi#comment107186899_60585905

Comment: @BlackSnow Well I am answering the question posed here, your other question is a very different problem.

Comment: well thanks for answering . any idea what i have to do know your solution did not work any idea please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209253/discussion-between-black-snow-and-matias-valdenegro).